# Why won't my pool pump breaker reset?

Tags: electrical

After extreme rain for a week my pool breaker has flipped off twice and now won't reset.  Should I wait for the ground to dry or contact an electrician?

Comment: By "won't reset" do you mean it trips again immediately after you turn it on, or you can no longer get it on at all? Do you see any exposed wiring or obvious shorts (remember, water is conductive)? If the pump has an outlet it's plugged into, you should try disconnecting it (to isolate if the problem is in the pump or outlet/wiring), and likewise with anything else plugged in on that circuit.

Answer (score 1):

As a commercial electrician I feel confident in a few things about this. Contact and electrician. You have several variables that need to be evaluated by someone with experience and the proper equipment.

Don't force the situation. It could be something simple like a failed breaker, or something more complex that could mean replacing pump parts, wiring, and so on.

Don't take the chance, bring in a professional.